# Some .java source codes from Android SDK not found

Tags: java, android, emacs, sdk

I'm new in Android SDK. I'm using Emacs as IDE (I know about Android Studio). I created a project and I compiled it from a script named gradlew (It was created automatically when the project was created). APK is created successfully. Now, I'm trying to implement (with FlyMake) syntax error checker. The command used to do this is the following:

> javac "main.java"

where `main.java` is the main of the application (there is only one file).

Obviously, javac doesn't know where is the SDK (API level 20). So I tell it as follow:

> javac -sourcepath "~/opt/android/sources/android-20" "main.java"

but it throws a lot of errors like "class not found". For example:

> /home/carlos/opt/android/sources/android-20/android/app/Activity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
>
> import android.content.IIntentSender;
>
> ```
>                 ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   class IIntentSender
>     location: package android.content

When I see the content of `android/content`, there is not a .java named `IIntentSender`

So, what's happening? Thanks for reading and answering!

Comment: The last time I used `javac` by hand, I used `-classpath`, not `-sourcepath`. The appropriate JAR for `-classpath` would be `~/opt/android/platforms/android-20/android.jar`, assuming that `~/opt/android/` is where your Android SDK is installed. `IIntentSender` is generated Java source code (from AIDL) and will not be in Java form in the SDK `sources` directory. So, if FlyMake requires `-sourcepath`, I expect that you're going to be in a world of hurt.

Comment: Jaja ok. I'll have in mind

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by `CommonsWare`:

> The last time I used javac by hand, I used -classpath, not -sourcepath. The appropriate JAR for -classpath would be ~/opt/android/platforms/android-20/android.jar, assuming that ~/opt/android/ is where your Android SDK is installed. IIntentSender is generated Java source code (from AIDL) and will not be in Java form in the SDK sources directory. So, if FlyMake requires -sourcepath, I expect that you're going to be in a world of hurt.

Thanks!